# How to get CLPlacemark from Location in SwiftLocation 5.1.0?

Tags: ios, swift, location, clplacemark

This is a library that doesn't have a very great documentation, In the past, I had problems migrating from a previous version to a modern version, and now, I have exactly the same problem again. In SwiftLocation 4 this is the way to get the placemark from a location, passing it the coordinates of that location:

```
SwiftLocation.LocationManager.shared.locateFromCoordinates(location.coordinate) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let places):
        guard let receivedPlacemark = places.first?.placemark else {
            return
        }
        logger.debug("Retrieved placemark: (receivedPlacemark.locality ?? "-")")
        self?.currentPlacemark = receivedPlacemark

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Constants.Notifications.placemarkUpdateNotification, object: nil)
    case .failure(let error):
        logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Constants.Notifications.placemarkUpdateNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Now, after upgrading to 5.1.0 version of SwiftLocation I simply can't find in GitHub or the cocoapods documentation of the library how to do the same with the actual version. `SwiftLocation.LocationManager.shared.locateFromCoordinates` doesn't exists and can't find anything similar.

How can I do that with 5.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process name for what you are trying to achieve is **Geocoding**.

From what I can see the location API changed a bit, so the code you are looking for is (from documentation):

```
let service = // insert your service here
SwiftLocation.geocodeWith(service).then { result in
    // You will get an array of suggested [GeoLocation] objects with data and coordinates
    print(result.data)
}
```

where `service` should equal to your service of choosing, but if we want to use Apple engine to get data for given coordinates, you can try:

```
let service = Geocoder.Apple(coordinates: location) //location must be CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

Comment: please, can you complete your sample code? swiftlocation location is not CLLocationCoordinate2D, and result.data returned by your function is not a CLPlacemark. maybe can you edit it adding those lost logic routines? Thank you

Comment: For that I would need to have more data. 
From your example - where do you get your `location.coordinate`?

Comment: location is returned from SwiftLocation.gpsLocation().then {
    print("Location is \($0.location)")
} check the "Getting user location via GPS" section of the documentation. And coordinate is a variable inside the "location" returned. I suposse that location.coordinate is CLLocationCoordinate2D but I still have the issue that I can't get the CLPlacemark from result.data in geocodeWith from your sample code

Comment: Based on documentation of SwiftLocation, the `geocodeWith` returns an array of `GeoLocation` elements.
 Based on your service (Apple from what I can understand) the `GeoLocation` object have a `representedObject` property that is filled with `CLPlacemark`.
But I would avoid using `CLPlacemark` alltogether and use `GeoLocation` from now on (it inherits all of the properties from Apple-class counterpart!) - [Source](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation/blob/f8ec8e97095eb3a5312370ad94b921768217625f/Sources/SwiftLocation/Request/Support%20Structures/GeoLocation/GeoLocation%2BApple.swift)

Comment: So basically if you want to get the `locality`, then `GeoLocation` has a property of `info[.locality]` that you can use. Simple as that :)

Comment: I need the CLPlacemark, as my original code does. I tryed your suggestion doing: let receivedPlacemark = result.representedObject but it gives to me this error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. Please check my original code and try to migrate it to the new version. I'm totally lost with this.

Comment: I would say you might be a very fresh person joining the Swift community. 
While reading the `GeoLocation` documentation from `SwiftLocation`, you can see that `representedObject` is `Any?` type, so you need to cast it to `CLPlacemark`
Luckily - you also have `clPlacemark` property that is already a correct type for you.

Comment: yes, my skills with ios are very low. I tryed casting it adding "as CLPLacemark", but now I'm getting this error: Value of type 'Result<GeocoderRequest.ProducedData, LocationError>' (aka 'Result<Array<GeoLocation>, LocationError>') has no member 'representedObject'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243650/discussion-between-ferus-and-nullpointerexception).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and this is what worked for me:

Inside your `LocationManager` create an optional `CLPlacemark` object:

```
@Published var placemark: CLPlacemark?
```

Then, in your `didUpdateLocations` func (still inside `LocationManager`) create a `CLGeoCoder` that uses your users location like so:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  guard let location = locations.last else { return }
  self.userLocation = location
                    
  let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation!) { placemarks, error in
    self.placemark = placemarks?.last
  }
}
```

`LocationManager` Code in full:

```
import CoreLocation
import Foundation
        
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
  static let shared = LocationManager()
            
  private let manager = CLLocationManager()
            
  @Published var userLocation: CLLocation?
  @Published var authorizationState: CLAuthorizationStatus?
            
  @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark?
        
  override init() {
    super.init()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  }
            
  func requestLocation() {
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }
}
        
extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    self.authorizationState = manager.authorizationStatus
                
    if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else if manager.authorizationStatus == .denied {
      print("Permission to location was denied")
    }
  }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    self.userLocation = location
                    
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation!) { placemarks, error in
      self.placemark = placemarks?.last
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the above to pass in your UI like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager.shared
        
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(locationManager.placemark?.locality ?? "Unknown Location")
        .font(.system(size: 40, design: .rounded)).bold()
    }
  }
}
```